# most performant way to layout objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, performance, oop, prototype, vtable

This is a pure performance question and I do not care about maintainability or readability.

This question is about how best layout OOP in the c#/c++ vein in javascript with respect to virtual and non-virtual methods. The performance concerns are mostly about passing the "this" object explicitly and looking up a method in a prototype versus an array. The four ways I have in mind are for the object:

```
 MyObjectvtable = [];
  function MyInnerObject() {}

  function MyObject() {
      this.mNum = 0;
      this.mObject = new MyInnerObject();
      this.mStr = "hello!";
      this.vtable = MyObjectvtable; 
  }

  function VirtualMethod() {
      var that = this;
      console.log(String(that.mNum) + that.mStr);
  };

  function NonVirtual(that) {
      console.log(String(that.mNum) + that.mStr);
  }

  MyObject.prototype.VirtualMethod = VirtualMethod;
  MyObjectvtable[0] = VirtualMethod;
  MyObjectvtable[1] = NonVirtual;

  pobj = new MyObject();
```

The four ways of calling the method here (VirtualMethod and NonVirtual) are briefly using the prototype call, passing pobj explicitly to NonVirtual, looking up VirtualMethod in the lookup table and looking up the method in the lookup table and explicitly passing the this object.

Method 1 - Virtual Prototype:

```
pobj.VirtualMethod();
```

Method 2 - NonVirtual

```
NonVirtual(pobj);
```

Method 3 - vtable-this-bind

```
pobj.vtable[0].bind(pobj)();
```

Method 4 - vtable-explicit-bind

```
pobj.vtable[1](pobj);
```

I've added testcases in JSPerf but they seem to be inconclusive, with firefox preferring the NonVirtual method (could be fastest but involves an access to a global function).

Here is the JSPerf case:
https://jsperf.com/virtual-vs-non-virtual-functions

Comment: Don't use `.bind(pobj)()` but `.call(pobj)`

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Using the normal JS conventions is what JS engines optimise for and will always be faster than trying to emulate some other language.

Comment: Even if you dive deep in v8 spec this will not guarantee that this will work fast on Chakra or other engines. So the real answer for this: work, measure, fix.